# Laravel AH01630: client denied by server configuration on Specific API routes

Tags: mysql, laravel, apache, centos, vps

I've a Laravel app which is has an API.
every thing works fine on localhost but when i deploy my app to hosting. I've notice that every API Route with these method (Delete,PUP,DELETE) didn't work, and it gave me the following error:

```
Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource.
```

my Apache Log:

```
[client 41.254.66.101:27968] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/username/public_html/api
```

i believe it's something with the server.

my server is running on CentosOS with CWP Panel.

Answer (score 0):

Apache is limited to serving files within its document root.

To fix it edit the config and ad another Directory

nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
<Directory /your/dir/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```